# web2py insert <link rel=canonical> into header

Tags: web2py, canonical-link

In web2py, from within a view, how do I insert a <link rel="canonical" href="..."> link into the header of the page. I know I can add a link tag with rel="stylesheet" using e.g. `{{response.files.append(URL('static','css/base.css'))}}`. Is there an equivalent for rel="canonical"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a block in the head section of the layout.html view:

```
{{block canonical}}{{end}}
```

Then in any view where you want to set the canonical link:

```
{{block canonical}}
<link rel="canonical" href="...">
{{end}}
```

A simpler option would be to include the following in the head of layout.html:

```
{{if response.canonical:}}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{=response.canonical}}">
{{pass}}
```

Then anywhere in a model or controller file you can do:

```
response.canonical = '...'
```

Comment: I will do the second. Thanks.

Comment: the second method should end with `{{pass}}` not `{{end}}`

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.